# How to deploy to Google App Engine in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, intellij-idea

I need to deploy Hello-World application to Google App Engine. I wanna do it through IDEA coz I have Ultimate one. ButI can't find how to do this. Could you please explain me what should I do to deploy, step by step ?

I created project from Idea template, added appengine-web.xml, specified registered app name. Any artifact/WAR hasn't been created yet.

I don't have menu item "Upload App Engine Application" as shown on http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/uploading-application-to-google-app-engine.html

My menu->"Tools" is:

[image]

Comment: +1. A flummoxed recent convert from eclipse gpe to intellij idea.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure Google App Engine [facet and SDK is configured correctly for the application](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/425/20130213203403.png).

You should get this menu then:

[image: Upload]

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to deploy to Google App Engine is using the Maven plugin.

```xml
<!-- The actual maven-gae-plugin. Type "mvn gae:run" to run project, "mvn gae:deploy"
     to upload to GAE. -->
<plugin>
   <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.5</version>
</plugin>
```

If you want to pursue this, then I would be more than happy to help you get it configured up  with follow up questions here.